# What are the sp_send_dbmail return values?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I have an email failing with function return value of '101' and @@error value of '0' (no rows are added to `sysmail_allitems`).

Where can I find documentation on return codes for this function?

Example code showing how I obtain the above values:

```
exec @result = msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'OBFUSCATED',  
    @recipients = @DL,  
    @subject = 'OBFUSCATED',
    @body = @emailBody,
    @body_format='html',
    @query = @reportQuery,
    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = @filename,
    @query_result_separator = @temp,
    @query_result_header = 1,
    @mailitem_id = @mailitem_id
    ;

    set @temp = @@ERROR;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error code 101 is because your query result attachment is larger than the ["MaxFileSize" Database Mail configuration option.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sysmail-configure-sp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

## Investigation

My first attempt at figuring this out was to run `sp_helpttext` on the `sp_send_dbmail` procedure to look at the implementation:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_send_dbmail';
```

The main body of that procedure returns a bunch of different status codes, from 0 up to 21.  It doesn't mention 101.  However, it calls into a few other stored procedures, like `sysmail_verify_profile_sp`, so I glanced in that one:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sysmail_verify_profile_sp';
```

But that only returns codes from 0 to 4.

Later the proc calls into `sysmail_verify_addressparams_sp`, let's check it out:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sysmail_verify_addressparams_sp';
```

Shucks, that only returns 0 or 1.

Next up is `sp_RunMailQuery`:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'sp_RunMailQuery';
```

It calls `sysmail_help_configure_value_sp` and `sp_isprohibited`, both of which only return 0 or 1.

### Black Box

At the end of `sp_RunMailQuery`, a system extended stored procedure is called: `xp_sysmail_format_query`.

We can't grab the source code for this, but I had a hunch from earlier in the proc:

```
--Get the maximum file size allowed for attachments from sysmailconfig.  
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_value_sp @parameter_name = N'MaxFileSize',   
                                            @parameter_value = @fileSizeStr OUTPUT
```

I noticed that you are using the attachment parameter, and the query results + max file size both get passed into the extended stored procedure as well.

### Repro City

I set my Database Mail maximum file size to 10 bytes, and then ran:

```
DECLARE @result AS INT;

exec @result = msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'DBMail',  
    @recipients = 'myemailaddress@something.com',  
    @subject = 'This is the subject',
    @body = 'This is the body',
    @body_format='html',
    @query = 'SELECT * FROM sys.messages;',
    @exclude_query_output = 1,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'big-file.csv',
    @query_result_separator = '===',
    @query_result_header = 1;

SELECT @result;
```

*Note: the "sys.messages" table has a bunch of string data that I knew would be more than 10 bytes.*

And sure enough, I got 101 as the return code:

[image: Error 101]

## Bugz

As [CR241](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/120854/cr241) helpfully [pointed out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227225/6141), the documentation *says* that @@ERROR should contain the error id number that corresponds to the appropriate error message in the `sys.messages` table:

> The error code for the statement that failed is stored in the @@ERROR variable. - [sp_send_dbmail - Return Code Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-code-values)

Instead it's 0 in my testing (which you noted in your original question).  This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Postscript: It is possible to run a query in a Query Window, copy results into Excel, save the file and find a file size under 100kb, then run the same query via sp_send_dbmail and have the attachment size threshold breached - because, for example, large source columns (such as varchar(8000)) (yes, even varchar) will output all whitespace in the mailed results, whereas whitespace will be excluded when copying from the query window. Workaround: explicitly type cast columns to types of smaller size.

Comment: For what it's worth, today I got a function return value of 102 and @@error = 0. I had noted previously this is the error code for a syntax error in the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

According to [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Return Code Values:

> A return code of **0** means success. Any other value means failure.

The error code for the statement that failed is stored in the `@@ERROR` variable.

`sp_send_dbmail()` returns `0` if the process of sending mails could be started without error. This means, mails have been set in the database mail queue, and for every mail the `mailitem_id` for the message is returned in the result set.

Any return value other than `0` means error. The precise error code of the failed statement can be seen in `@@ERROR`.

After using `sp_send_dbmail()`, the mail is sent asynchronously and it still can fail for many reasons. So if `sp_send_dbmail()` returns `0`, it does not mean final success.

You might look in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_faileditems` as in the case of error.

Comment: Thanks @CR241 - per comments on the question, however, the mail doesn't make it into `sysmail_allitems`, so won't be in `sysmail_faileditems`. Following SQL returns 0 rows. `use msdb; go select top 100 * from dbo.sysmail_faileditems;` If I query sysmail_allitems, there is no entry near the timestamp at which I recorded the error codes that were returned in the attempt to send mail.

Comment: Doh! Thanks.  A useful reminder as the code base I am looking at normally uses 0 for failure and positive integers for success (i.e. the opposite of this sproc).